# example.com to www.example.com .htaccess redirect working except one subdir

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, no-www

I've setup a redirect in `.htaccess` to consolidate `example.com` to `www.example.com` traffic on our Apache server.

Looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^centerline\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.centerline.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Works as expected, except for the blog.

If I go to `http://www.centerline.net/blog`, I get the blog fine.
If I go to `http://centerline.net/blog`, it redirects to the home page (which is the 404 default action).

I tried commenting out the two lines to consolidate `centerline.net` to `www.centerline.net`, and I still can't get to the blog via `centerline.net/blog`.

There's nothing else in the `.htaccess` related to the blog URL. For the blog, there are several lines that Wordpress inserted into the .htaccess, but commenting those out makes no difference. Just in case, that code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas where else to look? Or something I'm missing?

Comment: Redirecting to the home page is not really a good 404 action. It confuses users and doesn't give them a chance to tell you what's broken.

Comment: Total agree. That wasn't my call.

But that isn't the issue.

Comment: I've renamed the .htaccess file temporarily and I still get the same behavior from /blog/

So I've ruled out that it's the root dir's .htaccess causing the problem. Where else should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The root file had a .htaccess file. Everything in there was fine.

The /blog/ subdirectory though also had an .htaccess file with some duplicate rules. As soon as I renamed that .htaccess file (for all intents and purposes deleted it), `http://centerline.net/blog` redirected to `http://www.centerline.net/blog` without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant snippet from my .htaccess that works for me.  I'm going in the opposite direction from you (from `http://www.vyznev.net` to `http://vyznev.net`), but the principle should be the same:

```
#
# URL rewrite engine setup
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#
# Append directory slash (because Apache seems to prepend "www.")
#
RewriteCond /www/asiakkaat/vyznev/public_html/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://vyznev.net/$1/ [NS,L,R=permanent]

#
# Canonicalize host name
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^vyznev\.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?vyznev\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://vyznev.net/$1 [NS,L,R=permanent]
```

The first RewriteRule is there just to avoid double redirects for directory URLs without a trailing slash; you probably won't need it, but I included it just in case.

To be honest, I have no idea *why* the code in your question shouldn't work just as well as mine does.  But, in the absence of a better answer, I figured having a known working example might be of at least some help.